# Exchanging data between classes - DI, IoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

My setup is:

```
class ModelA { ... }
interface IModelARetriever {  IEnumerable<ModelA> GetObjects(); }

class ModelB { ... }
class DomainObject { List<ModelB> ModelBList; }
```

`DomainObject.ModelBList` could be appended using manipulated data from lists of `ModelA` objects, but not neccessarily. Where should I put the logic for this?

Should I create a method in `DomainObject` that takes a `IEnumerable<ModelA>`? That would mean changing the `DomainObject` for every possible source of data that can create objects of ModelB.

Should I create a separate `interface ModelBFactory` and extend that? This sounds best, but just want an expert opinion.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to either DI or IoC. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If I've read the question correctly, `ModelA` objects can be converted into `ModelB` objects. I'd say that calls for a `ToModelB()` method on `ModelA`. If the conversion is straightforward (say, just copying a subset of `ModelA`'s property values), I'd implement it in `ToModelB()` directly; if it's more complex (say, conditional copying of some property values, combination of values, arithmetic, etc) I'd have a `ModelAConverter` class which did the job.

I'd then add the `AddModelAObjects()` method you mentioned to `DomainObject`. You then have two choices of how you convert the `ModelA`s into `ModelB`s - you either have the `ModelAConverter` injected into `DomainObject`'s constructor and do the conversion in `AddModelAObjects()`, or into `ModelA`'s constructor and do the conversion in `ToModelB()`. I'd probably go with the latter, but it depends on what else the objects have to do.